# How to convert JSValue to Boolean?

Tags: delphi, boolean, tms, tms-web-core

I'm doing an API call using `TWebHttpRequest` and then parsing the response string to a `TJSObject`, but when I try to get a value from the `TJSObject`, it comes back as a `JSValue`. I need to take this `JSValue` and store it in a Delphi `Boolean` variable.

Here's my code:

```
LoginAPI.Execute(
  procedure(AResponse: string; AReq: TJSXMLHttpRequest)
  var
    JS: TJSObject;
    loginSuccess: Boolean;
  begin
    JS := TJSJSON.parseObject(AResponse);

    loginSuccess := JS.Properties['loginSuccess'];

    console.log(loginSuccess);
  end
);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [Error] Incompatible types: got "JSValue" expected "Boolean"

This error happens on `loginSuccess := JS.Properties['loginSuccess']` when I try to get the value and put it into the `Boolean` variable.

When I do `console.log(JS.Properties['loginSuccess'])` then I can see that the value is definitely a `Boolean` in the browser console. So I just need to know how to get it as a `Boolean` in Delphi.

---

I tried doing a `.AsBoolean`, but that doesn't work:

```
loginSuccess := JS.Properties['loginSuccess'].AsBoolean;
```

And the error I get then is:

> [Error] illegal qualifier "." after "Properties:JSValue"

---

So, how can I convert this `JSValue` to a `Boolean`?

Answer (score -1):

As per [pas2js's documentation](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Pas2js_Transpiler#The_JSValue_type) its booleaness can be enforced by comparing it to a Boolean literal:

```
var
  jso: TJSObject;
  jsv: JSValue;
  b: Boolean;
begin
  ...
  jsv:= jso.Properties['any'];
  b:= !(jsv== false);  // Value equals Boolean FALSE? Invert whole meaning.
```

Casting should only be done if you know what you're doing - but thanks to JavaScript's nature there's no guarantee that anything will always evaluate to either `true` or `false` without any further state (like `null` or `undefined`).

I have yet not found its actual definition, only [DefinedClassesWebKit.pas line #168](https://gitlab.com/freepascal.org/fpc/source/-/blob/main/packages/cocoaint/src/DefinedClassesWebKit.pas#L168) with:

```
JSValue = objcclass external;
```

...which means the actual definition is elsewhere. Because of the `{$modeswitch}`s I suspect binaries instead of source code.

Comment: I just checked now. I'm getting back `JSValue` and not `TJSValue`. So I'm not using `TJSValue` from `jbase`. This is something else.

Comment: Using `.AsBoolean` doesn't work on the TMS `JSValue`. I updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score -2):

If you know the property's value is definitely `Boolean`, then you can just cast it directly to `Boolean` like this:

```
loginSuccess := Boolean(JS.Properties['loginSuccess']);
```